Счетчик времени проведеного в войсе discord.py
Каким event в discord.py можно создать счетчик времени проведеного в войсе? Тоисть ивент, который будет начинать считать когда пользователь зайдет в войс. Существует ли такой?

API Reference
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after)

На основе этой функции можно сделать отслеживание времени, проведённого в голосовом чате
